# What is the function of the InputSpec layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, theano, keras-layer

I came across layer 'InputSpec' in a Keras code which was used in the following form in the code -

```
from keras.layers import InputSpec
var = InputSpec(ndim=4)
```

The official documentation says it 'specifies the rank, dtype, shape of every input to a layer'.
But in its usage above, it is not even passed a layer as input.
I tried to search but couldn't find much usage of this layer and didn't understand the documentation description for it. What is the functionality of this layer?

Comment: It is useful, when you create your own custom layer. You can find many examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89680/keras.layers.InputSpec)

Comment: Yes, I too saw it used in a custom layer, but could not get what is its use. It is not used as a layer in the model unlike other Keras layers and its output is being assigned to a class variable. So I am confused why it is called a layer. Could you kindly elaborate a bit on this?